# Hide div on medium / small resolution

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have two main divs on page and I want to hide on of them in case user comes from tablet / phone.

Based on [documentation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/) I tried something like:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="contrainer row">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
     SHOW ME ALWAYS!
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 hidden-md-down">
    HIDE ME ON SMALL 
  </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. Second div will display all the time. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: the documentation link points to `alpha` while the css you're including is the `beta`

Comment: use `bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6` version , so you can use `hidden-md-down` class. In beta version it's not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`4.0.0-beta` no longer has `hidden-*`, see [Migrating to v4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#responsive-utilities):

> Our responsive utility classes have largely been removed in favor of explicit display utilities.
>
> The .hidden and .show classes have been removed because they conflicted with jQuery’s $(...).hide() and $(...).show() methods. Instead, try toggling the [hidden] attribute or use inline styles like style="display: none;" and style="display: block;".

Comment: Thanks, somehow I missed that. So there is no way to do it by pure CSS based on screen resolution?

Comment: there still is, is just that instead of `hide` it is now `display`. See [this migration](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#utilities).